# Limiting a search to records from last_request_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I am trying to figure out how to display a count for records that have been created in a table since the last_request_at of a user.

In my view I am counting the `notes` of a `question` with the following code:

```
<% unless @questions.empty? %>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= h(question.notes.count) %>
  end
end
```

This is happening in the `/views/users/show.html.erb` file. Instead of counting all the `notes` for the question, I would only like to count the notes that have been created since the users `last_request_at` datetime. I don't neccessarily want to scope notes to display this 'new notes' count application wide, just simply in this one instance.

To accomplish I am assuming I need to create a variable in the User#show action and call it in the view but not really sure how to do that.

Other information you may need:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end


class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a named scope and then use it only when it applies:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :added_since, lambda { |time| {
    :conditions => time && [ 'created_at>=?', time ]
  }}
end
```

This should only enforce conditions if a time is provided. If you submit a nil time, the default behavior is to scope all notes.

This way you can do something along the lines of:

```
@new_notes = @user.notes.added_since(@user.last_login_at)
```

Adding a named scope does not alter the default scope.